# SQL query CASE value don't give value in IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query that I created:

```
select a.caseticket, line, process, step, equipment
    , case when ISNULL (logcount, 0) = 0 then 'New'
    else b.status end as [Status]
    , isnull(b.logcount, 0) as LogTotal 
from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZEPB_CaseEntry] a 
left join (
    select y.CaseTicket, z.Check_Person, z.Status, y.Logcount
    from (
        select distinct caseticket, MAX(ID) as ID, COUNT(*) as logcount 
        from [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZEPB_CaseLog]
        group by caseticket
    ) y
    left join (
        select ID, check_PERSON, status
        FROM [SQLIOT].[dbo].[ZEPB_CaseLog]
        group by ID, check_person, status
    ) z on y.ID = z.id
) b  on a.CaseTicket = b.CaseTicket
```

Which gives me this result:

```
| caseticket |  line  | process |  step   |  equipment  |    Status   | LogTotal |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     10     |   A01  |   QWE   |  BYRTT  |     A123    |   Progress  |     4    |
|     11     |   A09  |   ert   |   axcv  |     789     |   Cancel    |     2    |
|     12     |   ghf  |   get   |   wrwt  |     r5we    |   Close     |     2    |
|     13     |   uyt  |   876   |  ,j,jh  |     7i7     |     New     |     0    |
```

'[New] status is a NULL value, only having [New] for this display only.

I now want to only show rows with `[Status]` of `Progress` and `New`. So I added at the end of the SQL query:

```
where [Status] in ('Progress', 'New')
```

But during testing, only row with `Progress` appeared in the query and `New` doesn't. What my be preventing it?

Comment: . . I think there is a much simpler query to get what you want.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `WHERE` condition  as below.

`WHERE ([Status] IN ('Progress') OR ISNULL(b.logcount, 0) = 0)`

The reason your condition did not work is when you add condition in `WHERE [Status] IN ('Progress', 'New')` it will check it as `b.Status IN ('Progress', 'New')` and your `b.Status` will not have value as `New`.

---

Alternatively you can wrap your entire query with `SELECT * FROM (Your entire query) t WHERE [Status] IN ('Progress', 'New')` which will apply condition on `Status` values returned from `INNER Query`.

Comment: I understand the answer but not the upvotes.  This doesn't work if `b` only has values that are neither `'Progress'` nor `'New'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff From question `I now want to only show rows with [Status] of Progress and New`. So in case if `b` only has values that are neither `'Progress'` not `'New'` then it won's display any record. I think that is expected result, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this is to put the filtering conditions in the `on` clause:

```
on a.CaseTicket = b.CaseTicket and
   b.Status IN ('Progress', 'New')
```

Comment: From question `[New] status is a NULL value, only having [New] for this display only`, so `b.Status IN ('Progress', 'New')` will only join with `Status='Progress'`. And as it is `LEFT JOIN` all records with `Status` other than `'Progress'` will have `NULL` values. Due to which from `case when ISNULL (logcount, 0) = 0 then 'New'` it will return `New` for statuses `NULL`, `Cancel`, `Close`, etc.